# Waiting for an async method to end in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, monitor

Sample code:

```
    class Program
{
    static readonly object locker = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func();
        Func();

        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }

    static void Func()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(locker);
        Action act = () =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    };
        act.BeginInvoke(a =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("exiting..");
                            Monitor.Exit(locker);
                        }, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Func done...");
    }
}
```

Ideally the console would print out:

```
Func done...
exiting...
Func done...
exitting...
```

But, I'm getting:

```
Func done...
Func done...
exitting...
```

and then Monitor.Exit throws the exception

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

What is the error here? What's the preferred way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you doing async if you're wanting to wait for it to complete before continuing?

Comment: The code may not be representative of the actual problem :)
The way its called from Main method isn't the way it would be used in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitor.Enter(locker) is on the current thread, Monitor.Exit is on a different thread as it is invoked from your current thread.
Thus you need to use Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse as well, but ManualResetEvents are easier in your case.

Answer (score 4):

`Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` calls have to be made on the same thread. In your sample you call `Monitor.Enter` on the UI thread and `Monitor.Exit` on a thread created for the asynchronous invocation triggered by `BeginInvoke`.

If you want to wait for the async operation to be finished within `Func` you could do it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func();
        Func();

        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }

    static void Func()
    {
        Action act = () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                };
        IAsyncResult actAsyncResult = act.BeginInvoke(a =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exiting..");
                }, null);

        Console.WriteLine("Func done...");

        act.EndInvoke(actAsyncResult);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless in your scenario you could then just invoke the delegate synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wait for an event to complete by using [ManualResetEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). Sorry I don't have any experience with Monitor. But I am using the ManualResetEvent / AutoResetEvent classes for testing callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Thread shudn't close Monitor

```
Monitor.Exit(locker);
```

this is a problem

Answer (score 0):

This error is very misleading. It really doesn't mean what it looks like it means.  It actually means that `Monitor.Exit` is called before you called `Monitor.Enter` on a sync object.

Your `Monitor.Exit` call happens on a different thread from the `Monitor.Enter` call -- the two don't see each other's sync objects.